# Unable to diff dot-files in Mac's FileMerge

Tags: macos, diff, filemerge

I have set my FileMerge not to ignore any file.
However, it ignores my dotFiles.

**How can you make FileMerge to diff dotFiles?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the leading dot is merely a conventional hint to the OS that the file is hidden (inherited from UNIX) I would imagine that removing the leading dot from the filename would allow the utility to see and diff the files.

Comment: Some files have a leading dot for a reason. Renaming those files is not a generic solution, though it can help in special cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use opendiff -Mac's builtIn command to launch dotFiles in FileMerge.
You can find a solution at the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916822/unable-to-diff-files-in-two-separate-branches-in-git/917557#917557).