# Unable to convert dot-files to non-dotfiles safely

Tags: shell, mv

I run unsuccessfully in Mac

```
mv .* *
```

and

```
mv .* ./*
```

My files disappeared into thin air.

**How can you convert dot-files to non-dotfiles safely?**

Comment: You do realize that they're dotfiles for a reason, don't you? If you do this with files that programs expect to find (e.g., .bashrc), you're really going to stuff up your system.

Comment: @Pax: this doesn't have anything to do with the fact that these are dot-files.  This is because wildcard expansion works differently in unix shells than it does in DOS' and Windows' command line interface

Comment: @Pax: I realize that. I just need to convert my files to non-dotFiles in order to be able to use FileMerge to diff changes in dotFiles.

Comment: @masi: lol, what about diff file1 file2?    I would look into using a different diff tool so u can see the dot files (again, not sure what type of system you're on)

Comment: @Roy: I am using at the moment Mac.

Comment: An answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912589/unable-to-diff-dot-files-in-macs-filemerge) suggests using the `opendiff` command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for i in `ls -d .*`; do mv $i "`echo $i | sed 's/^.//'`"; done
```

or, much easier,

```
rename 's/^.//' `ls -d .*`
```

if your system have got it.

In zsh, you could just use .* safely, but in bash you'll have to use `ls -d .*`

Comment: bash should always error out for . and ..; I don't think any sane implementation could possibly succeed with "mv . ''" or "mv .. .".

Comment: Absolutely. But then it would not suck; and bash just can't not.

Comment: "ls -1" is not necessary: ls automatically outputs in 1 column if stdout is not a terminal device (e.g. if it's outputting to a pipe).

Comment: Fixed that. Never needed ls in this case anyway.

Comment: @alamar: How deep does your 1st command go? -- I run it by accident at Home.

Comment: @alamar: Your 1st command is dangerously powerful. Does the second command go to subdirectories too?

Comment: Both would only affect files and directores (but not their contents) in the current directory. They're essentially equal.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `mv` to rename multiple files like that.  What you want is [mmv](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/mass-rename.html) (get it [here](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/mmv.html)).

```
mmv .\* \#1
```

You have to escape the asterisk to prevent bash from expanding it.  Use the -n flag to do a test run to make sure what will happen is what you want.

You could also do this in shell scripting but I much prefer `mmv` because the -n flag shows what it would do.  You'd have to alter your script to echo instead of mv, which seems more dangerous than dropping the -n flag (especially when you get more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part about this is selecting dotfiles without selecting "." and "..".

- `ls .??*` is sometimes used for this, since it forces the filenames to be three or more characters long.  There is a risk though, of overlooking a dotfile with a short name, such as ".x"
- `ls -d .*` prevents directories from being expanded, but it doesn't filter out "." or ".."
- The `find` command could be used, as in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*'`.  The maxdepth limits it to the current directory and not subdirectories.  The -type f limits it to files, eliminating directories such as "." and "..".  Then again, maybe you want to rename the .ssh directory to ssh.

Here's an alternative that selects dotfiles while avoiding "." and "..".

```
ls -A | sed -n 's/^\.\(.*\)/mv ".\1" "\1"/p' | bash
```

The -A lists all files and dotfiles, yet eliminates "." and ".." for us.  Then the sed command selects only those lines with "." as the first character, and prints out appropriate "mv" commands, complete with quotes in case you have a bizarre dotfilename with a space in it.

Run it without the "| bash" first, to see what mv commands are generated.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what type of system you're on, but it looks unix like,  i would do

ls -1 .?* | cut -b1- | xargs -i{} mv .{} {}

this lists, everything that starts with a ., but isn't . or .., then cut the first column off, then pipe that list to a move command

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, there is usually a `rename` utility available (a perl script, if I am not mistaken):

```
rename 's/^.//' .*
```

It is available on a Mac. You can install it by following tips at [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20050630022203488).

Comment: I am trying to install the command at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915174/unable-to-install-linuxs-rename-to-mac and to add it to MacPorts at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915144/unable-to-find-port-dependencies-for-rename-in-util-linux-for-macports

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler:

```
for x in .*; do mv $x ${x/./}; done
```