# Unable to install Linux's rename to Mac

Tags: linux, macos, rename

I read the [tutorial](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20050630022203488) which advises me to run  at util-linux package

```
./configure
```

I get

```
configuring util-linux-2.12q

You don't have <scsi/scsi.h>
You don't have <linux/blkpg.h>
You don't have <linux/kd.h>
You have <locale.h>You have <langinfo.h>
You have <sys/user.h>
You have <uuid/uuid.h>
You have <rpcsvc/nfs_prot.h>
You don't have <asm/types.h>
You don't have <linux/raw.h>
You have <stdint.h>
You don't have <sys/io.h>
You have inet_aton()
You have fsync()
You have getdomainname()
You have nanosleep()
You don't have personality()
You don't have updwtmp()
You have fseeko()
You have lchown()
You don't have rpmatch()
You have <term.h>
You have ncurses. Using <ncurses.h>.
You have termcap
You don't need -lcrypt
Strange... Static compilation fails here.
You don't have native language support
You have __progname
You don't have <pty.h> and openpty()
You have wide character support
You don't have SYS_pivot_root
You have a tm_gmtoff field in struct tm
Your rpcgen output does not compile - using pregenerated code
You have zlib
You don't have blkid
```

It then advises me to run the following command at misc-utils

```
make rename
```

I get the following warning

```
cc -pipe -O2 -mtune=i386 -fomit-frame-pointer -I../lib -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -DNCH=1   -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DSBINDIR=\"/sbin\" -DUSRSBINDIR=\"/usr/sbin\" -DLOGDIR=\"/var/log\" -DVARPATH=\"/var\" -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/share/locale\" -O2  -s  rename.c   -o rename
ld warning: option -s is obsolete and being ignored
```

**How can you install rename -command for Mac?**

Comment: This is pragramming related, since I need the command to be able to use Diff-tools. Please, move the question to Serverfault.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a warning, not an error.

I've just tried this myself and it has built a rename executable.

Comment: How did you manage to do it? I run unsuccessfully: ./rename File1 Neww, but it does not change the file name.

Comment: It works fine, but you need to read the man page: rename takes three arguments.

Example usage:

% touch testrename
% touch testrename2
% ls
testrename  testrename2
% ../rename test different *
% ls
differentrename  differentrename2
%

Comment: I did exactly the same as you in trying to use the command. How did you installed the app?

Comment: @yangyang: Thank you for your answer! The problem was in the use of wrong package. Your pieces of advice work for util-linux-2.12p.

Answer (score 3):

Easily install rename using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/)

```
brew install rename
```

Answer (score 1):

Do compile `rename` from linux. There are some minor differences to the indications in the [tutorial](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050630022203488). I used version 2.22 from the file [util-linux-2.22.tar.gz](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.22/util-linux-2.22.tar.gz)

Download it and uncompress it. Go to the uncompressed folder in a terminal.

Don't just run `./configure`, use this command with flags instead:

`./configure --disable-su --disable-sulogin --disable-login`

then from that very same folder, NOT changing into misc-utils, you do `make rename`

That's all, in the current folder you'll have the executable and in the misc-utils the man documentation if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use `mv` instead of trying to compile `rename`?  Maybe even alias it to `rename`?

(EDIT: Ignore my comment about build-essentials - [as pointed out by yangyang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915174/915219#915219), it looks like it should have built ok anyhow)

Comment: @Colin: I am trying to change the names of my files at my Git-repo, such that I can use fileMerge -tool, since they cannot read dot files.

Comment: You should be able to change the names with mv.  Maybe I don't understand - is rename used in a script for Git or something?

Comment: @Colin: rename is used to rename different files easily. It is much easier to rename many dot files with it, than with mv.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function rename { from=$1; to=$2; shift 2; for i in "$@"; do j=`echo $i | sed "s/$from/$to/"`; mv "$i" "$j"; done }
```

Paste it into your .profile or .bashrc and run it just like the Red Hat rename utility:

```
$rename foo bar *.txt
```

Turns foo1.txt, foo2.txt and foofoo.txt into bar1.txt, bar2.txt but, somewhat irritatingly, barfoo.txt. 
Maybe someone can tweak it to fix this.

Test it by putting 'echo' before 'mv' so that it outputs a list of all changes it will make without making them.

Comment: Although, Red Hat's rename utility, and zsh workarounds, also mentioned around the place, als have the same behaviour whereby foofoo.txt -> barfoo.txt after running rename foo bar *.txt. So perhaps this isn't a problem if emulating a better rename utility is the point.