# Unable to diff files in two separate branches in Git

Tags: git, unix, merge, diff

I have FileA in branchA and FileB in branchB.

The problem is that I can access only one file at time.
I would like to be able to compare the files by FileMerge or meld, since they are the only diffTools whichI have found for Mac.

**How can you diff by meld/FileMerge the two files**?

---

[Solved]: **1st developed Problem:** FileMerge does not allow standard input

> Masi: You can use [opendiff to allow FileMerge](http://kerneltrap.org/index.php?q=mailarchive/git/2007/3/29/242485/thread) to have files from standard input. So the next problem is to find how to make git's diff tool to use opendiff.

---

**2nd developed Problem:** to make Git's diff tool to use opendiff in Mac

Comment: The problem is not that git isn't using opendiff, it's that README doesn't exist on master.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use "[git mergetool](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html)" for merging, and in modern git (meaning version 1.6.3 and later) "[git difftool](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html)" for comparing using graphical tools. Of course you would have to configure them first, but they do some autodetection (with some hardcoded preference, of course), and if I remember correctly opendiff support is built in.

And then of course you would be able to use your graphical tool (opendiff / FileMerge) as you would use ordinary "git diff", for example

```
prompt> git difftool somebranch:UNREADME otherbranch:README
```

Comment: As I wrote git-difftool is available only in git version 1.6.3 and later (check output of "git --version").

Comment: @problem solved: MacPorts has old Git. I needed to update it. -- Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 61):

git supports branch names as part of the repository paths.  Eg if you have the following files in your repository, `README` only on `master`, and `UNREADME` only on `branch`:

```
master:README

branch:UNREADME
```

You can diff them via git with:

```
git diff branch:UNREADME master:README
```

You can get a repository artifact to standard output with `git show`:

```
git show branch1:UNREADME
```

So if your external diff utility can take 2 files on the bash prompt, you can diff them with something like:

```
diff-command <(git show branch1:UNREADME) <(git show master:README)
```

Where the `<(...)` bash syntax takes the output of the enclosed command, runs it in a pipe and places the file path of the pipe on the command line.

Comment: How can you do the same with an external file-diff-merger? -- I run unsuccessfully in Mac % open -a filemerge Heee/master:.profile master:.profile

Comment: FileMerge.app doesn't accept input from stdin. You might have luck with this script that google produced: http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/11/21/435536

Comment: You might also try Changes.app, which has a command line utility and can accept input from stdin... http://changesapp.com/

Answer (score 37):

If you're currently checkout out to branchA, for example, you can use the command:

```
git diff branchB path/to/common/file/between/branches.txt
```

You can then edit the diff if you want a subset of the changes, or leave it as is, and `git apply` the diff as a patch. As for a GUI tool that does this, hopefully someone else will have a suggestion there.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES), you need something similar to the following in your .git/config file:

```
# Our diff algorithm
[diff]
    external = opendiff
```