# Get a diff of a file in two different branches

Tags: git

I have two branches A, and B. (they're both remote branches too). Is there a way to do a diff of a single file between the two branches? It's located in the same place in both branches etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to diff files in two separate branches in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916822/unable-to-diff-files-in-two-separate-branches-in-git)

Comment: And [this is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/916914/960558)

Comment: @LazyBadger: It may be an answer but it's not a *good* answer. There's no reason to specify the filename twice.

Comment: @Jefromi - in original question it's a must due to rename

Comment: Sure. That doesn't make it useful for this question, though. (And I'm sure there's a duplicate question here somewhere, but I do not think that one's a good candidate. That poster wants to use a difftool.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `git diff branch1 branch2 -- <File1>[, <File2>...]` to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

```
git diff A:File..B:File
```

[Git Reference](http://gitref.org/inspect/) (abot git diff), [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/3_comparing_commits_-_git_diff.html), ["git - compare branches"](http://blog.m1key.me/2011/05/git-compare-branches.html) for details