# git: how to diff between branchA:file.php and HEAD:otherfile.php

Tags: git

In my case, my HEAD I am working on as a file called `otherfile.php` which was originally made by `cp file.php otherfile.php`.

Now, after editing both `file.php` and `otherfile.php` for some time, I want to see how much my `otherfile.php` has changed from the original `file.php` (whose commit is tagged with `branchA`).

How can I do this? And does this question make sense?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916822/unable-to-diff-files-in-two-separate-branches-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git diff branchA:file.php HEAD:otherfile.php
```

Comment: Ok. Apparently the HEAD file has to be the second argument. This answer is what I tried, but with the HEAD file first, so I guess that's why it didn't work. Thanks.